# Numeric keypad dot/comma behavior

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, datagrid

I have a query. I have changed DecimalSeparator as (,) and GroupSeparator as (.) in control panel. Now opening the Excel sheet and type (5.5 , (.) changed to (,) i.e. (5.5) ----->(5,5). I need to know how this behavior works in DataGridView? I have tried to find it, but I'm still confused. Please let me know what is the behavior of the datagrid after changing the decimal separator.

Comment: Well what happens if you try it?  If you have tried it, what happens that you do not expect?

Comment: it won't act as a number because a comma is not a maths operator. Why even replace the character in the first place?

Comment: You mean you want to make the dot key enter a comma instead while typing in dataGridVew?is it a winforms application you're trying to code?

Comment: `DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider` and `DefaultCellStyle.Format` of column are designed for this purpose.